# SSH Connection freezes after minutes of unuse?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I run a RaspberryPi with Raspbian operation system. I have installed a WLAN stick and connected the pi only over WLAN to my network.

I can access the pi with

```
ssh pi@pi-ip-address
```

This works fine but after a couple of seconds or minutes of unuse the connection freezes. It means that I cannot type in the terminal any more. It takes a while until I can use the same connection and continue to use it without creating a new connection.

When I do

```
ping pi-ip-address
```

after the connection freezes the my cannot be reached with the ping. It takes about a minute or so until the ping succeeds and I can continue to use the SSH connection to the Pi.

**What causes this problem and how can I solve it? How can I guarantee that the SSH connection is stable and will not be interrupted when unused for a short period of time?**

**Edit:** A similar problem also occurs when I want to access the raspberryPi over http. It takes a while into the pi responds.

Comment: Have you tried using KeepAlive? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084288/keep-ssh-session-alive

Comment: The acronym WLAN is already taken, choose something else to call your WiFi stick. It makes questions like this very confusing. Also, if you cannot ping then this is not an SSH problem at all. It sounds like your WiFi stick is just not very good.

Comment: A similar problem also occurs when I want to access the raspberryPi over http. It takes a while into the pi responds.

Comment: @krowe WLAN is already taken by [wireless networking](http://superuser.com/tags/wireless-networking/synonyms), which certainly seems to fit with the usage here. Are you suggesting the OP specifically say WiFi, so we know it isn't Bluetooth or Zigbee or some other type of WLAN?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you add `TCPKeepAlive yes` into your ssh_config or in your sshd_config then it will never timeout.
2. If you want to set a certain amount of time before you lose connection to the server then in your `$HOME/.ssh/config` or in your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (on mac it is the `/etc/ssh_config`) add `ServerAliveCountMax 0` and `ServerAliveInterval <How ever many seconds you want it to stay alive for>`.
3. If you want to force your ssh clients off of your server if they idle for too long then goon your server and go to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (On mac it is the `/etc/sshd_config`) `ClientAliveCountMax 0` and `ClientAliveInterval <How ever many seconds you want it to stay alive for>` **remember** this option will override the 2nd option above.

   - TCPKeepAlive yes/no for ssh and sshd
   - ClientAliveCountMax for sshd
   - ClientAliveInterval for sshd
   - ServerAliveCountMax for ssh
   - ServerAliveInterval for ssh

Comment: if you have any questions about my post, please ask I am happy to help.